# Add a dependency in a project using gem

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am having a problem when I use Jekyll to build a website and host it on github. The website uses a relative path dependency [jekyll-relative-links](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links), but this dependency is installed on the local disk:

> /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/jekyll-relative-links-0.5.3

I will not find this dependency when I push the site onto github, so I would like to ask if I can install this dependency in the project. Thanks.

Comment: No, unfortunately one cannot extend GH pages functionality with 3rd party gems.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin if OP would build the site locally with jekyll and then push it to  Github as HTML it could be done though right?

Comment: @maxpleaner most likely, yes, but this is not what was asked initially; I agree that’s the way to go, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub Pages [officially supports](https://pages.github.com/versions/) `jekyll-relative-links   0.5.3`, so you can just install It as usual:

1. Add the following to your site's Gemfile:

   `gem 'jekyll-relative-links'`
2. Add the following to your site's config file:

   `plugins: 
       - jekyll-relative-links`

---

More [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-jekyll-plugins-to-a-github-pages-site/)